# Freeradius don't start after upgrading to 3.0.22-1

Tags: upgrade

After upgrading from version 3.0.21 to 3.0.22 freeradius does not start on Ubuntu 18.04:

#freeradius -X
FreeRADIUS Version 3.0.22
Copyright (C) 1999-2021 The FreeRADIUS server project and contributors
There is NO warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A
PARTICULAR PURPOSE
You may redistribute copies of FreeRADIUS under the terms of the
GNU General Public License
For more information about these matters, see the file named COPYRIGHT
Starting - reading configuration files ...
including dictionary file /usr/share/freeradius/dictionary
...
rlm_ldap (ldapName): Bind successful

## Instantiating module "expiration" from file /etc/freeradius/mods-enabled/expiration

## Instantiating module "reject" from file /etc/freeradius/mods-enabled/always

## Instantiating module "fail" from file /etc/freeradius/mods-enabled/always

## Instantiating module "ok" from file /etc/freeradius/mods-enabled/always

## Instantiating module "handled" from file /etc/freeradius/mods-enabled/always

## Instantiating module "invalid" from file /etc/freeradius/mods-enabled/always

## Instantiating module "userlock" from file /etc/freeradius/mods-enabled/always

## Instantiating module "notfound" from file /etc/freeradius/mods-enabled/always

## Instantiating module "noop" from file /etc/freeradius/mods-enabled/always

## Instantiating module "updated" from file /etc/freeradius/mods-enabled/always

## Instantiating module "eap" from file /etc/freeradius/mods-enabled/eap

## Linked to sub-module rlm_eap_md5

rlm_eap (EAP): Failed to link rlm_eap_leap: /usr/lib/freeradius/rlm_eap_leap.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
/etc/freeradius/mods-enabled/eap[2]: Instantiation failed for module "eap"

Answer (score 0):

It might have to do with a [new feature introduced in 3.0.22](https://freeradius.org/release_notes/):

> - Remove native support for Cisco LEAP. It is insecure, and should not be used. Proxying LEAP is still supported.

You might need to adapt your config or roll back to 3.0.21.

Comment: Ok thanks Ludwig... I use Ubuntu 18.04 and upgrading via 'apt update' and 'apt dist-upgrade' this occurs... maybe all the users are affected

Answer (score 0):

This one also affected me. My solution was to comment out the leap section of the eap config file, all working after that. Probably a good reminder to turn off all unused configurations in production.

Comment: Thansk Fred... Worked for me